# Show that this optimization problem has a closed form solution or at least it's convex

Tags: geometry, optimization, convex-optimization, quaternions

Let $(q_i)_{i\leq n}$ be unit quaternions, $a_{ij}$ be unit quaternions, and $w_{ij}$ be positive real numbers. We consider the expression:$$\sum_{i,j} w_{ij} \arccos(\operatorname{Re}(q_i a_{ij} \bar{q_j})).$$ Can we find a closed form of the $q_i$ that minimizes this sum? Alternatively, can we prove that this problem is convex, so that it can be solved with a solver?

EDIT:
Perhaps a more convenient writing:

Denoting
$q =  (q_i)_{i\leq n}$, $A =  (a_{ij})_{ij}$ and $E_{ii}=e_ie_i^{T}$ therefore if we set $A_{ij}=E_{ii}AE_{jj}$ the formula can be rewritten $$\sum_{i,j}w_{ij}\arccos(\operatorname{Re}(q^{T}A_{ij}\bar{q}))$$

Comment: We can do neither one. And it looks quite a difficult optimization task. What are you trying to do with it and what was the original question this monster came from?

Comment: Given a set of predicted relative frames given as quaternions (aij~Fj^TFi) I want to get the best Fi that would fit the total representation 

Comment: Well, "best fit" can be given several different meanings. Did you try to play with them to see if there is some still reasonable but less hopeless expression to minimize?